# ¿Como utilizar un preloader hasta que finalicen distintas funciones con peticiones al servidor, jquery, framework7?

Tags: jquery

Buen día Actualmente tengo las siguientes funciones que se ejecutan al mismo tiempo. El problema que tengo es que cuando se ejecuta una función se activa el preloader `myApp.showIndicator();` pero al mismo tiempo al finalizar la primer funcion activada que ha devuelto una peticion del servidor se ejecutara `myApp.hideIndicator();` por lo tanto se oculta el preloader antes de tiempo, aun cuando no haya devuelto la información el servidor en las otras funciones.

Aca un ejemplo de las funciones que ejecuto:

```
    cantidadLlaves(idPedido);
        function cantidadLlaves(idPedido) {
             myApp.showIndicator(); //Con esta funcion se ejecuta el preloader
                return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                    axios({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: `https://URL/metodo1?IDPedido=${parseInt(idPedido)}`,
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
myApp.hideIndicator(); //Con esta funcion se oculta el preloader
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                })
        }

    function obtenerOfertasAdicionales(idPedido) {
                myApp.showIndicator(); //Ejecutando el preloader.
                return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                    axios({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: `https://URL/metodo2?IDPedido=${parseInt(idPedido)}`,
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        myApp.hideIndicator();//Ocultando el preoloader

                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                }

    )
                }

        function obtenerMaterialImpreso(idPedido) {
     myApp.showIndicator(); //Ejecutando el preloader.
                    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                        axios.get(`https://URL/metodo3?IDPedido=${idPedido}`, {
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                            }
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
     myApp.hideIndicator(); //Ocultando el preloader.
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error)
                        })
                    })
                }



 if (cod_emp === "5"){
            cantidadCuponesCR(cedula, idPedido);
     myApp.showIndicator(); //Ejecutando el preloader.
            function cantidadCuponesCR(cedula, idPedido) {
                    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                        axios({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: `https://URL/metodo4?Cod_Trib=${cedula}&IDPedido=${parseInt(idPedido)}`,
                            headers: {
                                Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                            }
                        })
                        .then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                             myApp.hideIndicator(); //ocultando el preloader.                   
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error)
                        })
                    })
            }
        }



     if (tipo_socio === "1"){
                var tipo = 1;//Oricash
                cantidadCuponesOricash(cod_cliente, tipo);
                function cantidadCuponesOricash(cod_cliente, tipo) {
     myApp.showIndicator(); //Ejecutando el preloader.
                        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                            axios({
                                method: 'GET',
                                url: `https://metodo5?Cod_Cliente=${cod_cliente}&Tipo=${parseInt(tipo)}`,
                                headers: {
                                    Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token
                                }
                            })
                            .then(function (response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                cupones_oricash = response.data;
     myApp.hideIndicator(); //ocultando el preloader.
                            }).catch(function (error) {
                                console.log(error)
                            })
                        })
                }
            }
```

Por lo tanto como podría hacer para ejecutar un `myApp.showIndicator();` y hasta que la ultima función devuelva su información del servidor ocultar el preloader con un `myApp.hideIndicator();`

De antemano muy agradecido, bendiciones.

Comment: mmm no se si será lo ideal, pero te tiro una idea. Por que no declaras un contador donde vayas incrementando con cada success. De este modo si son 4 funciones por ejemplo, cada vez que termines una verificas. Si count  === 4 entonces myApp.hideIndicator(). Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,

Puedes usar `jQuery.when(...)`, crea un Array de peticiones y al finalizar todas puedes ocultar el indicador de "Cargando...".

Es muy sencillo de usar. Esta es la documentación (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)[https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/]

```
jQuery.when(jQuery.ajax("peticion1"), jQuery.ajax("peticion2"), jQuery.ajax("peticion3"))
   .done(function(data1,  data2, data3){
         // Acá puedes hacer que se oculte el indicador
   });
```